# Collapsible Comments in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there an extention that makes it possible to subordinate javascript code that is written under comments like that?:

```
//comment {
       code that should be collapsed
//}
```

Comment: You're looking for something like the C# regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `#region` for it.

```
//#region
some code
some code
some code
some code
some code
//#endregion
```

You'll then be able to collapse the whole thing into one line.

Comment: Oh that's great thanks a lot